# Missing layouts in blender 2.8

Tags: interface

I recently updated my blender 2.79 to blender 2.8 and I'm missing some of the new workspace layout tabs that they introduced in blender 2.8. I watched several video tutorials on YouTube they seem to have more workspace layouts tabs. Some of the layouts that I'm missing are sculpting, texture painting and layout.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a '+' button that allows to add layouts:

[image]

Comment: So foolish of me. I completely overlooked the add layouts button. Thanks a lot for respond